# Changed the URL and ROOT. Main Page won't load. Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, root

I am trying to redesign a website from a friend and it's chaotic as hell. Now I am stuck a bit.

The old domain it something like http://www.website.com/folder/
I am trying the get rid out of the "folder", so I changed the setting in the wordpress setting and the root in the web-provider. The whole website is working fine, also the Wordpress admin area. But if I'm trying to get into the "home" page, it won't load - or it is loading endlessly.

Do you have any idea how I could fix it?

Regards and thanks,
Natts

Answer (score 0):

A piece often forgotten is the `.htaccess` file (found in the root of your WP install); I especially suspect it because you're going from a subfolder to no subfolder.

Back it up, then override it with [the default WordPress values](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) (or delete it and go to Settings -> Permalinks in WP Admin)

Default `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```